# How to update values in a CSV column using a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

```
list=[8,5,3,4,5,7,3,5]
```

Screenshot of CSV file in Excel

[image: Screenshot of CSV file in Excel]

I would like to replace all the values in the csv file using python. So for example all the values under items to be replaced with values from the list. So in row 2 under Items header the value 4 to be replaced with 8 from the list and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: To replace values in a CSV file you will need to first read the entire thing into memory, update the values in memory, and then rewrite the entire file. You can easily read and write CSV files using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in Python's standard library. It is also well documented with lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['items'] = [8,5,3,4,5,7,3,5]
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks It worked I was stuck. Really Appreciate The Help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating all the values in a column, you can start from a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

# now update the column
newlist=[8,5,3,4,5,7,3,5]
df['items'] = np.array(newlist)

#write back to csv
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank You so much Really helps, I appreciate the support